# sapply as.numeric not working inside a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, sapply

I'm using a for loop to read every sheet in an Excel file, process it and save it in a list. First iteration does it without problem, but when it gets to i=2, the following error shows up:

```
Error:
! Assigned data `sapply(EstContratos[cols.name], as.numeric)` must be compatible with existing data.
✖ Existing data has 1 row.
✖ Assigned data has 3 rows.
ℹ Row updates require a list value. Do you need `list()` or `as.list()`?
```

This is the code:

```
mysheetlist <- excel_sheets(path="whatever/EstadoContrato.xlsx")

datalist<-list()

i=1

for (i in 1:length(mysheetlist)){
  EstContratos <- read_excel(path="whatever/EstadoContrato.xlsx", sheet = mysheetlist[i])


EstContratos<-EstContratos %>%
  filter (!row_number() %in% c (1:15))

EstContratos<-Filter(function(x)!all(is.na(x)), EstContratos)

colnames(EstContratos)<-c("Cap","UM","CantContr","VrUni","VrUniTot","VrTotalContr",
                          "CantEjec","VrTotalEjec","CantXEjec","VrXEjec")

EstContratos<-EstContratos%>%
  select(Cap,VrTotalContr,VrTotalEjec,VrXEjec)

EstContratos$VrTotalContr<- gsub(",", "",EstContratos$VrTotalContr)
EstContratos$VrTotalEjec<- gsub(",", "",EstContratos$VrTotalEjec)
EstContratos$VrXEjec<-gsub(",", "",EstContratos$VrXEjec)

EstContratos<-EstContratos %>% drop_na(Cap)

cols.name <- c("VrTotalContr","VrTotalEjec","VrXEjec")
EstContratos[cols.name] <- sapply(EstContratos[cols.name],as.numeric)

EstContratos[c('CapCod', 'Capítulo')] <- str_split_fixed(EstContratos$Cap, ' ', 2)

EstContratos<-EstContratos%>%
  select(CapCod,VrTotalContr,VrTotalEjec)

ResumenContratos<-aggregate(EstContratos[,2:3], by = list(EstContratos$CapCod), sum)

datalist[[i]] <- ResumenContratos

}

ConsolidadoContratos = do.call(rbind, datalist)
```

I'm not sure why it says assigned data has 3 rows when its the same EstContratos dataframe that in the second iteration has 1 row. Maybe it's taking the EstContratos dataframe from the first iteration which does in fact have 3 rows, but I don't know how that's possible.

(Sorry if it's not clear its my first time posting a question)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly and your intention is to transform those columns to numeric type, you can try:

```r
EstContratos[ , cols.name] <- lapply(EstContratos[ , cols.name], as.numeric)
```

or

```r
EstContratos[ , cols.name] <- apply(EstContratos[ , cols.name], 2, as.numeric)
```

Comment: Yes, I need to transform those columns to numeric type for each sheet in the xlsx file the for loop reads. Using this code I get the same Error. The weird thing is that if I use the code outside the for loop replacing  [i] by [1] (as if doing the for loop manually for the first iteration) it does it without any errors. When I try to do the same for the second iteration (using [2]) it shows the error.

Comment: Apologies there was a typo in my initial post, please see edited version!